# Select/Count elements from a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, .net-2.0

Lets say i have a List like this.

```
private List<TestClass> test()
{
    List<TestClass> tcList = new List<TestClass>();
    tcList.Add(new TestClass { ModulePosition = 1, TopBotData = 2, prop3 = 3 });
    tcList.Add(new TestClass { ModulePosition = 1, TopBotData = 4, prop3 = 5 });
    tcList.Add(new TestClass { ModulePosition = 1, TopBotData = 2, prop3 = 6 });

    return tcList;

}
```

What i want to do is, i want to return all the elements which have `ModulePosition = 1` and `TopBotData = 2`. I would also need the count of it satisfying the given condition. Here in this case it will be 2. Without using LINQ as i am using .net 2.0

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems have you had implementing a solution to this problem?  Do you have some non-working code from your current attempts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap it up in a method and just yield return the results that match your criteria

```
public IEnumerable<TestClass> GetTests(List<TestClass> tests)
{
   foreach(var v in tests){
      if(v.ModulePosition == 1 && v.TopBotData == 2)
         yield return v;
   }
}
```

And Then

```
List<TestClass> tcList = new List<TestClass>();
tcList.Add(new TestClass { ModulePosition = 1, TopBotData = 2, prop3 = 3 });
tcList.Add(new TestClass { ModulePosition = 1, TopBotData = 4, prop3 = 5 });
tcList.Add(new TestClass { ModulePosition = 1, TopBotData = 2, prop3 = 6 });

var results = new List<TestClass>(GetTests(tcList));
var count = results.Count;
```

Comment: fixed to use List<T>(IEnumerable<T>) ctor

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Count(List<TestClass> tests)
{
   int counter=0; 
   foreach(var v in tests){
      if(v.ModulePosition == 1 && v.topBotData == 2)
         counter++;
   }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do this. 
Inside the if add any condition that you want

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tcList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tcList[i].TopBotData == 2 && tcList[i].ModulePosition == 1)
            {
                result.Add(tcList[i]);
            }
        }

        return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

you do this. 
Inside the if add any condition that you want.

In order to know the number of element just do `result.Count`

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tcList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tcList[i].TopBotData == 2 && tcList[i].ModulePosition == 1)
            {
                result.Add(tcList[i]);
            }
        }

        return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eoin's answer, but I'd do a more generic method, such as

```
private List<TestClass> GetByModuleAndTopBot(List<TestClass> list, int modulePosition, int topBotData)
{
    List<TestClass> result = new List<TestClass>();
    foreach (TestClass test in list)
    {
        if ((test.ModulePosition == modulePosition) &&
            (test.TopBotData == topBotData))
            result.Add(test);
    }
    return result;
}
```

therefore you can get the result you want by calling this method as follows:

```
GetByModuleAndTopBot(tcList, 1, 2);
```

and count it with `.Count`, as its return type is a `List<>`.

Answer (score 0):

[`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has a [`FindAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that is almost identical to LINQ's `Where`:

```
return tcList.FindAll(
  delegate(TestClass x) { return x.ModulePosition == 1 && x.topBotData == 2; });
```

In newer versions of .NET, I'd recommend LINQ and lambda expressions, but for .NET 2.0, the above is probably the most concise way to do what you want (and therefore, IMHO, probably a good way).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a predicate:

```
private static bool MyFilter(TestClass item)
{
  return (item.ModulePosition) == 1 && (item.TopBotData == 2);
}
private static void Example()
{
  List<TestClass> exampleList = test();
  List<TestClass> sortedList = exampleList.FindAll(MyFilter);
}
```